# Firing focusin and focusout not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use the `focusin` and `focusout` triggers in JQuery. I am using it with Bootstrap Popovers.

Currently, for some odd reason in my thoughts, it doesn't work.

What is wrong with this?

Here's a JSFiddle with the current state: http://jsfiddle.net/8jshY/

And the JS code:

```
$('input[type=text]').focusin(function() {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
});

$('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
    $(this).popover('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
$('input[type=text]').popover({trigger:'focus'});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jshY/1/)